# How to bypass a 2TB core dump file system limit?

Tags: x86-64, redhat, coredump

I have a huge VM address space in a multi-threaded program. Typically it runs in ~5TB of virtual, and of that only touches up to 16GB of resident set. I map HugePages, and allow them to be dumped from their sections.
When the RedHat 6.3 + Kernel 3.0.29 system forces a crash dump,
most of the resident set gets dumped, but the core file stops at 2TB.

```
-rw------- 1 root root 2.0T Aug 21 21:15 core-primes-6-1377119514.21645
```

top reports ~4TB in this instance.

```
21726 root     -91   0 4191g 7.1g  13m R 99.7  5.6   2:39.06 50 primes
```

gdb reports the core is truncated
BFD: Warning: /export0/crash/core-primes-6-1377119514.21645 is truncated: expected core file size >= 4488958177280, found: 2133738614784.

Is there some magic foo to allow the kernel to dump more than 2TB of this
process? The filesystem is ext3, and has plenty of space.
The VM for the unused memory is never touched.

Comment: The underlying etx3 filesystem with a 4KB block size tops out at 2TB max file size. Switching to an XFS filesystem gives a much larger max file size, and the core dump completes up to ~16TB. However it takes 30 minutes to dump. Switching to ext4, the native max file size is 16TB. The dump completes in < 4 minutes. You just have to remember to update fstab. mkfs.ext4 -LEXPORT0 -Tlargefile /dev/sda10

Answer (score 2):

The underlying etx3 filesystem with a 4KB block size tops out at 2TB max file size. Switching to an XFS filesystem gives a much larger max file size, and the core dump completes up to ~16TB. However it takes 30 minutes to dump. Switching to ext4, the native max file size is 16TB. The dump completes in < 4 minutes. You just have to remember to update fstab. mkfs.ext4 -LEXPORT0 -Tlargefile /dev/sda10. Using largefile hints to the filesystem that more space than files are needed.

Answer (score 0):

`ulimit -c` is the command to verify and change the allowed maximum size of core files created; it is documented in the [bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) man page. Use something like

```
ulimit -c 16000000
```

As root, you can run

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```